# Dig doesn't print anything on Linux terminal

Tags: ubuntu, dig

'dig baidu.com' works fine. But when I execute 'dig NODES.L.ROOT-SERVERS.ORG TXT +short +tcp | head -10',there is nothing printing on terminal. The RFC 7108 saids as following. And I confuse strongly of why I have nothing to show.
The RFC show: 
`dig NODES.L.ROOT-SERVERS.ORG TXT +short +tcp | head -10
   "abj01.l.root-servers.org" "Abidjan" "" "Cote d'Ivoire" "Africa"
   "abj02.l.root-servers.org" "Abidjan" "" "Cote d'Ivoire" "Africa"
   "akl01.l.root-servers.org" "Mangere" "" "New Zealand" "AsiaPacific"
   "akl41.l.root-servers.org" "Mangere" "" "New Zealand" "AsiaPacific"
   "akl42.l.root-servers.org" "Mangere" "" "New Zealand" "AsiaPacific"
   "akl43.l.root-servers.org" "Mangere" "" "New Zealand" "AsiaPacific"
   "akl44.l.root-servers.org" "Mangere" "" "New Zealand" "AsiaPacific"
   "ams01.l.root-servers.org" "Haarlemmermeer" "" "Netherlands" "Europe"
   "anc01.l.root-servers.org" "Anchorage" "Alaska" "United States"
     "NorthAmerica"`
And mine is:
`root@hewan-virtual-machine:/home/hewan#  dig NODES.L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET IN +short +tcp | head -n 10
root@hewan-virtual-machine:/home/hewan#`

Comment: What does `dig NODES.L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET TXT` print on its own, without the unnecessary options added?

Comment: ;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 22901
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; MBZ: 0005 , udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;NODES.L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. IN  TXT
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 5  IN   SOA a.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019031301 14400 7200 1209600 3600000
;; Query time: 61 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 10 17:42:44 CST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you're trying to query **doesn't exist anymore** in DNS. Pay attention to the status line:

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 33790
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

RFC 7108 documented the "current" practice of maintaining the L-root at the time it was written (**2014**), but it seems that the system has changed since then and the nodes themselves no longer carry information about all the other nodes. (The list of L-root nodes is still available [as a YAML file](https://www.dns.icann.org/imrsmap/json/map.latest.yaml) over HTTP.)

Comment: uh...Actually I want to get the list of L-root nodes's actual IP (that is used only for admins and not published in the root zone). Is there any way to get it?

Comment: It's in the YAML file that I linked to. Look under `Instances` → `Identifiers`.

Comment: like this?<br/>`nslookup aa01.us-sjc.l.dns.icann.org`<br/>`名称:  aa01.us-sjc.l.dns.icann.org
Addresses:  2001:558:fe0c:2::2
 69.241.90.14`

Comment: Is 69.241.90.14 is aa01.us-sjc.l.dns.icann.org's(one mirror of L-root) actual IP?

Comment: It is supposed to be, yes. (But it is not required to answer DNS requests – remember that it's a management address. The DNS software is often only configured for the anycast address.)

Comment: yeah, I have another question that there are some root do not publish these mirrors. Is there any way I get them?